# C# Date set as textbox, which send data to textfile as other format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a text box that is set to todays date. The problem is its formatted on the form for visual ref as 07/12/12 but it needs to be on the report(word doc/data thru mail merge) as July 12, 2012. the user can edit the date, it just populates with todays date as that is used the most.

```
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy");
        LetterDate.Text = today;

        var Date = String.Format(DateTime.ParseExact(LetterDate.Text,"MMddyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString(), "MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Date gives the output as 7/12/2012 12:00:00 AM --- im so lost at to why/how its even getting that format.

I know this should be easy, but its end of day and im just not seeing it.

Comment: So you are wanting Date to be 7/12/2012 ?

Comment: im looking for output as "June 12, 2012" (for the date in a letter)

Comment: Micah, im fairly new to this site. I do vote up and answer what i think is appropriate. Am i not doing something else?

Comment: ahhh. thanks for the tip, ill go back and review it.

Comment: Anytime glad you got your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy");
        LetterDate.Text = today;
        var date = Convert.ToDateTime(LetterDate.Text).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

take a look on this site for more reference:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[String Format for DateTime C# Corner](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Best Regards

Comment: for var Date = LetterDate.Text.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
I get error argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: var Date = String.Format("{MMMM d, yyyy}", LetterDate.Text); gives me 'argument is not used is format string'
I even did the {0}:{mmmm dd, yyyy}, letterdate.text which made it compile but gave an error when run saying bad format. I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Dude.. you rock! that was it. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13823/discussion-between-bizapps-and-user1143606)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the format July 12, 2012 with out using DateTime.Parse like this:

`LetterDate.Text.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");`

Comment: This wont work because im setting a date for a text box to pre-populate, if the user changes the date in the textbox it needs to reflect the new date. make since? Its been a long day.

Comment: @user1143606 I have updated my answer to take value from textbox